# get newtork tab in developer tools programmatically with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, developer-tools

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the information I see in the network tab of chrome/firefox with some get request in php or any API in JavaScript.

I have some links, I want to pass each of these links to my script, the script retrieves the "network" data, then I will extract some info from these using some string filters.
I know how to manipulate strings/arrays once I can get the network tab content stored in a variable.

I'm looking for equivalent of opening developer tools, select network tab, then "copy link address" for the urls I see there.
I'm trying to get each request url like in this photo.
[image]
So how do I achieve this?

Edit:

Here's what I tried:

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPjJZRWAqkE';

print_r(get_headers($url));

print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
?>
```

But this doesn't print the request urls

In js I tried:

```
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4-OxOmsqR0";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('HEAD', url, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders();

console.log(headers);
```

But the request was blocked with CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll only be able to access the headers/content of the request in Javascript if the request is also made in Javascript. eg `<img src="...` downloads are impossible to track. (except from the context of a privileged extension, maybe, or something like that)

Comment: ok so Javascript can't retrieve the network tab. Is it feasible with PHP? or even c++? how does the browser get them in the first place?
All I need is getting a list of the urls I see in network tab? isn't this  part of the headers?

Comment: It can, if the request is made via Javascript. If you control the server, then sure, you could use PHP to check the headers and content of what gets sent to the client

Comment: PHP runs on the server side, so unless the client browser is making a call to your own server you can’t track requests using server side language.

Comment: I understand that php is server side, but afaik I can still do a GET request to other servers from my pc/server without any problems, am I wrong? please correct if I'm mistaken :) 
Please see my updated answer, I tried to clarify my question a bit.

Comment: I’m curious which headers you want to access. When I look at the response headers from `'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4-OxOmsqR0` the only ones that look interesting are the Set-Cookie headers. But you can’t access those from frontend JavaScript no matter what — even if the response has an Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Browsers block all frontend JavaScript code from any access to the value of the Set-Cookie header. And the 'Request URL' shown in devtools doesn’t show up in the response headers anyway. Nor in the request headers — because it’s not a header.

Comment: Anyway, if the *request* details as shown in the devtools Network pane are what you actually want to access, then the answer is that you can’t get to those details from frontend JavaScript. The Network pane shows the details of the request as the browser constructed it *after* the browser ran your frontend JavaScript code. The browser adds particular headers to the request on its own, so there’s no way you can get access to those from your frontend code (because of the fact the headers get added after the browser runs your frontend code).

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks for your answer. Yes  the request details as shown in the devtools Network pane are what I want. I see, so due to how browser runs frontend js, It won't work. But is it feasible with some server side language php/Node.JS? For example, My server does a GET request or something to the URL,and constructs these network headers just like a browser?